# Get tx.origin to send from the contract

Tags: solidity

User -> Contract A -> Contract B

Now when I execute a function from contract A as a user to contract B, it'll execute as contract A, is there any way to execute a function from contract B as the User?

```
contractAImplementationofB.somefunction(various inputs);
```

Can I do like

```
tx.origin.contractAImplementationofB.somefunction(various inputs);
```

Or is there some version of this in solidity?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR Yes, you can execute a function of Contract B as User, but it cannot modify the state of contract B (storage variables).**

Let's review your example.

**User (EOA) -> Contract A -> Contract B**

In your example where contract A calls a function of contract B, for the execution of contract B's function, `msg.sender` is contract A, and `tx.origin` is User.

However, instead of doing a regular call to contract's B function, you could `delegatecall()` to that function from contract A. The effect of using `delegatecall()` is that both `msg.sender` and `tx.origin` will be User for the purpose of executing contract B's function.

You may think that `delegatecall()` solves your issue since `msg.sender` would always be User in this example, but it probably doesn't. In addition of preserving `msg.sender`, `delegatecall()` also executes the function of contract B **in the context of contract A**. This means that only the storage variables of contract A will be changed by whatever contract B does, and the storage variables of contract B will remain unaffected by the transaction.

Comment: An excellent point about `delegatecall` - had forgotten those tricks. Thanks for the new answer :)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't spoof the sender in such a way. The only options a contract has are `msg.sender` and `tx.origin` - but it's up to the contract code to decide which one it wants to use.

This is mostly a security issue so that the previous sender (relayer) of the transaction is always known. A lot of contracts would break if `msg.sender` could be changed.